# Каким способом сократить код?

Tags: javascript, jquery, циклы

Задача: реализовать автоматическое заполнение чек-бокса при клике на картинку с подсвечивание, так же и обратно, при отметке чек-бокса подсвечивать выбранную картинку. Код я написал, но уверен что это можно сделать короче. Подскажите как?

Код прилагается ниже:

```
var coupons = $(".field-name-field-coupon-image img");
        var checkbox = $("#edit-submitted-offers-choose-your-offer input");
        $(checkbox).change(function () {
            if ($(checkbox[0]).attr("checked")) {
                $(coupons[0]).addClass("coupons-border-selected");
            } else {
                $(coupons[0]).removeClass("coupons-border-selected");
            }
            if ($(checkbox[1]).attr("checked")) {
                $(coupons[1]).addClass("coupons-border-selected");
            } else {
                $(coupons[1]).removeClass("coupons-border-selected");
            }
            if ($(checkbox[2]).attr("checked")) {
                $(coupons[2]).addClass("coupons-border-selected");
            } else {
                $(coupons[2]).removeClass("coupons-border-selected");
            }
        });
        $(coupons[0]).click(function () {
            if ($(checkbox[0]).attr("checked")) {
                $(checkbox[0]).removeProp("checked");
                $(coupons[0]).removeClass("coupons-border-selected");
            } else {
                $(checkbox[0]).prop("checked", true);
                $(coupons[0]).addClass("coupons-border-selected");
            }
        });
        $(coupons[1]).click(function () {
            if ($(checkbox[1]).attr("checked")) {
                $(checkbox[1]).removeProp("checked");
                $(coupons[1]).removeClass("coupons-border-selected");
            } else {
                $(checkbox[1]).prop("checked", true);
                $(coupons[1]).addClass("coupons-border-selected");
            }
        });
        $(coupons[2]).click(function () {
            if ($(checkbox[2]).attr("checked")) {
                $(checkbox[2]).removeProp("checked");
                $(coupons[2]).removeClass("coupons-border-selected");
            } else {
                $(checkbox[2]).prop("checked", true);
                $(coupons[2]).addClass("coupons-border-selected");
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

попрбуйте так

```
var coupons = $(".field-name-field-coupon-image img");
var checkbox = $("#edit-submitted-offers-choose-your-offer input");

$(checkbox).change(function () {
  checkboxChange(0);
  checkboxChange(1);
  checkboxChange(2);
});


$( coupons ).each(function(index) {
    $(this).on("click", function(){
        if ($(this).attr("checked")) {
            $(this).removeProp("checked");
            $(this).removeClass("coupons-border-selected");
        } else {
            $(this).prop("checked", true);
            $(this).addClass("coupons-border-selected");
        }
    });
});

function checkboxChange(chbId){
   if ($(checkbox[chbId]).attr("checked")) {
     $(coupons[chbId]).addClass("coupons-border-selected");
   } else {
     $(coupons[chbId]).removeClass("coupons-border-selected");
   }
}
```

Comment: Все почему-то решили повторить ошибку с `.attr("checked")`. Не знаю с чем это связано (то, что у автора так, - не в счет). Код по-прежнему можно ощутимо укоротить, можно исправить ошибку с `.attr("checked")`, можно отойти от негибкого и нелогичного (зачем проверять все `checkbox` при смене одного?) `checkboxChange(0); checkboxChange(1); checkboxChange(2);` в пользу проверки только текущего. Галочка в чекбоксе при клике на картинку в данном коде, кстати, не проставляется (даже при исправленном `.attr("checked")`). Код без исправления последней ошибки: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hzye51s6/).

Answer (score 1):

Можно привязать клик на картинке к чекбоксу средствами HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chb1" />
<label for="chb1"><img src="http://example.com/s.png" /></label>
```

Ну и циклы.

```
for(var i=0; i<coupons.length; i++) {
    addHandler_Coupons(i)
}

function addHandler_Coupons(i) {
    $(coupons[i]).click(function () {
        if ($(checkbox[i]).attr("checked")) {
            $(checkbox[i]).removeProp("checked");
            $(coupons[i]).removeClass("coupons-border-selected");
        } else {
            $(checkbox[i]).prop("checked", true);
            $(coupons[i]).addClass("coupons-border-selected");
        }
    });
}
```

---

Ещё можно группировать элементы в логические блоки, и бегать по DOM относительно нужных элементов.

```
<div class="block">
    <input type="checkbox"> <img src="">
</div>
<div class="block">
    <input type="checkbox"> <img src="">
</div>
```

И поставить единый слушатель на событие `click` на все блоки.

```
$('.block img').click(function() {
   var input =  $(this).closest('.block').find('input');
   var checked = input.prop("checked");
   input.prop('checked', !checked);
});
```

Comment: По поводу финального варианта: 1. `e.target` можно заменить на `this`, а `e` убрать из аргументов функции. 2. `.parent()` - негибкое решение, стоит заменить на `.closest('.block')`. 3. `.attr("checked")` - это за гранью добра и зла (если, конечно, вы не используете жутко старую версию jQuery). Нужно заменить на `.prop("checked")` или `input[0].checked`. Аналогично в следующей строке: либо через `.prop()`, либо через `input[0].checked`. На данный момент код не рабочий (с jQuery 1.11.0 и 2.1.3) [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o7vopug9/).

Comment: @Regent спасибо за уточнение, поправил ответ с учётом ваших замечаний.

Comment: На здоровье. Про сокращение варианта _"ну и циклы"_ стоит расписывать? И главное: почему в обоих случаях рассматривается только клик по `<img>`, а клик по `checkbox` игнорируется? Это ведь половина задачи.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(checkbox).each(function(){
    $(this).on('change', function(){
        $(this).attr("checked") ? $(this).addClass("coupons-border-selected") : $(this).removeClass("coupons-border-selected");
    })
})
$(coupons).each(function(){
    $(this).on('click', function(){
        if ($(this).attr("checked")) {
            $(this).removeProp("checked");
            $(this).removeClass("coupons-border-selected");
        } else {
            $(this).prop("checked", true);
            $(this).addClass("coupons-border-selected");
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: тут кажется вместо `coupons[0]` будет `this`

Comment: Да, точно) Спасибо

Comment: Спасибо, помогли нубу)

Comment: Спасибо, помогли нубу, только вот this не совсем то. Дело в том что картинки и чекбоксы это разные елементы, не связанные между собой.

Comment: This - уникальный идентификатор текущего элемента с которым идет взаимодействие. Для каждого элемента checkbox - this - это один чекбокс, для каждого элемента coupons - это одна из картинок.

Comment: @Moonvvell ваш код можно очень сильно сократить. Не говоря уж опять про `.attr("checked")`, что вообще не вяжется со свойством `.checked`.  А ещё во втором обработчике (`click` для `coupons`) почему-то проверяется и изменяется `img` вместо `input`. Укороченный код без исправления ошибки: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tjmwtsm2/).

Answer (score 1):

Идея состоит в том, чтобы по клику на `checkbox` добавлять/удалять класс у соответствующего (равного по индексу) `<img>` в зависимости от значения свойства `checked`, а по клику на `<img>` - менять значение свойства `checked` у соответствующего (равного по индексу) `checkbox` в зависимости от наличия класса.
Селекторы `$coupons` и `$checkbox` упрощены для примера.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $coupons = $("img");
    var $checkbox = $("input");
    var className = "coupons-border-selected";

    $checkbox.on("change", function() {
        var index = $checkbox.index(this);
        $coupons.eq(index).toggleClass(className, this.checked);
    });

    $coupons.on("click", function() {
        var index = $coupons.index(this);
        $(this).toggleClass(className);
        $checkbox[index].checked = $(this).hasClass(className);
    });
});
```

[Полный пример в fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4sdLx32p/).